# Is there a way to insert an .wav file in my Rblogdown website?

Tags: r, audio, blogdown

I would like to insert an .wav audio file directly into my website without using a second party solution like Soundcloud. Is this possible? So far I couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: ``<html>
<audio controls>
  <source src="audio.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio></html>`` wouldn't simple html work?

Comment: thanks 4 helping out.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to tell me if it works!

Comment: now. your code worked like a charm in my Rmarkdown file.

Comment: Awesome! Even simple html code can work really well with R (Rblogdown).